# Didn't find AppCompatActivity on path

Tags: android

I am new to AndroidStudio learning how to code via the Udacity program, "Android Basics". I am currently on Lesson 3.13 "Running Hello World App on Your Phone". I have followed the instructions step by step and have tried to launch the app on my phone (OnePlus5). However, as soon as I press the play button, the message "MyApp has stopped". It gives me the option to re-open the app but the message "Happy Birthday keeps stopping" appears.

```
02-10 12:45:08.376 7992-7992/com.example.android.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                             Process: com.example.android.happybirthday, PID: 7992
                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.happybirthday/com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2847)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)


    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1190)
02-10 12:45:08.377 7992-7992/com.example.android.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2837)
                                                                                        ... 9 more
                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
                                                                                     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                            ... 12 more
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                            ... 15 more
02-10 12:45:08.378 7992-7992/com.example.android.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.happybirthday, PID: 7992
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.happybirthday/com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2847)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1190)
02-10 12:45:08.378 7992-7992/com.example.android.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2837)
                                                                                        ... 9 more
                                                                                    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity;
                                                                                     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
                                                                                            ... 12 more
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.android.happybirthday-KxEHHSDZIiC4FI1vJwwPDw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
                                                                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                            ... 15 more
02-10 12:45:08.379 7992-7992/com.example.android.happybirthday D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
```

Comment: post your code of play button's file

Comment: Please add the AndroidManifest xml and both Gradle files  to the question

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the class to see it's correct, check if the Activity is the correct package and if the Activity is declared in the manifest.